# Any /polls URL always call index() function in views.py

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views, django-urls

```
polls/urls/py


from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

url('', views.index, name='index'),
url('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),

# ex: /polls/5/results/
url('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
# ex: /polls/5/vote/
url('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]


views.py

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Question
from django.template import loader

# from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
context = {
    'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
}
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


def detail(request, question_id):
return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)


def results(request, question_id):
response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
return HttpResponse(response % question_id)


def vote(request, question_id):
return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

url=http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls

url=http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/

url=http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/results

These all urls are giving same mapping same function index(). Any help will be appreciated

Comment: first of all never mix up two different versions' docs for same task. you mixed up the functionalities of both which resulted you in to undesire outcome

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's **really** important to make sure that you are following the tutorial that matches your version of Django. Here are the links for [Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) and [Django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/).

You are getting the unexpected behaviour because you are mixing the old `url` and new `path` syntax. If you are using Django 2.0, change the import and update your URL patterns:

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),

    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),

]
```

If you are using an earlier version of Django, you need to use regexes instead. For example, the Django 1.11 tutorial gets you to write:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Django is this? Your url patterns look like a mixture of 2.0 and older routing.

Your empty url pattern would probably match anything so not another route ever gets called.

For Django 2.0 + do what @Alasdair suggest above for older Django version something like below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```